# Image processing using GLCM

Tags: java, image-processing, glcm

I need to extract homogeneity, correlation, contrast, and energy texture features from a Gray-Level Co-Occurrence Matrix (GLCM).

Can anyone tell me any simple algorithm which can calculate these texture features for java implementation?

Comment: Did you have a look at the ImageJ plugin for [texture analysis](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/texture.html)? In addition, a quick search on the ImageJ mailing list yielded [this post](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Update-to-GLCM-Texture-td3698049.html) that links to additional source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are so called haralick features.
You could implement them on your own scince they are really easy.

A quick search for 'haralick java' turned up this code which, at a first glance, looks like something you could use. [Code for Haralick Features](http://code.google.com/p/jfeaturelib/source/browse/src/de/lmu/dbs/jfeaturelib/features/Haralick.java?r=12f3307427400fc77434e39ffed43c2c62d4bb98)

It is part of the jfeaturelib. [Project Site](http://code.google.com/p/jfeaturelib/)